# create dynamic table within procedure?

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to create dynamic table within procedure but  i am getting error please 
 tell me whats the error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_sms_bundle_25 (
   MON        VARCHAR2,
   YEAR_P     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YY'),
   QUARTER    VARCHAR2,
   TYPE       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'NEW')
IS
BEGIN

   IF UPPER (QUARTER) = 1
   THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE (''SMS_Bundle_25_'''|| UPPER (MON)|| '''_Q'''|| UPPER (QUARTER)|| '||''_''||'''|| UPPER (YEAR_P)|| ''')
   AS
   SELECT customer_id, otxact
     FROM ordertrailer INNER JOIN orderhdr_all ON ohxact = otxact
    WHERE sncode = 343 AND ohentdate = ''1-aug-2014'' AND ohstatus = ''IN''
   END';
   END IF;
END;
```

The error msg is

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
>
> begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise
>   return select update while with       <<    close current delete
>   fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit
>   forall merge pipe ORA-06512: at "FI_SDINE.CHECK_SMS_BUNDLE_25", line 9
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you included the error you are receiving.

Comment: Not sure where to start... perhaps you should look at the SQL manual and figure put a valid statement, before you try to execute it from a procedure. Creating a table on the fly is rarely a good idea anyway though.

Comment: the statement are valid and the error is ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
ORA-06512: at "FI_SDINE.CHECK_SMS_BUNDLE_25", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @xXghostXx `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE`? Syntax doesn't exist for creating Oracle tables.

Comment: okay i see something like this for create view i thought thats will works with creating table... what that ways called so i search about on the net i searched for dynamic create within procedure oracle but thats does not give me what  i need thanks

Comment: Just create a more general table or temporary table and reference that in your code. There is no need to create a table dynamically here and it isn't possible to do that in a block as your are trying to do anyway.

Comment: It's not just the 'or replace' part though; you're running the DDL (create statement) inside an anonymous PL/SQL block (i.e. inside begin/end *within* your dynamic statement); your table name is in the wrong place; you seem to be creating the table name by concatenating the passed values but with singles quotes in the name; you don't have any column definitions (names or data types). It really isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Creating a table on the fly is a bad idea; creating a table per month is a bad idea. Maybe look at partitioning. But also maybe talk to your DBA.

Answer (score 1):

As well as 'or replace' not being valid as part of the [`create table` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#i2201774), you're enclosing the DDL statement inside another anonymous PL/SQL block, you're trying to put the table name inside parentheses, and you're including quote marks - which are not allowed in an (unquoted) object identifier. So if you pass in argukments AUG, 14, 1 NEW then your dynamic statement is trying to run:

```
BEGIN CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ('SMS_Bundle_25_'AUG'_Q'1||'_'||'14')
   AS
   SELECT customer_id, otxact
     FROM ordertrailer INNER JOIN orderhdr_all ON ohxact = otxact
    WHERE sncode = 343 AND ohentdate = '1-aug-2014' AND ohstatus = 'IN'
   END
```

The BEGIN/END make is a block and the DDL statement isn't valid in PL/SQL; that's why you're having to use execute immediate in the first place. If you change your construction to:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SMS_Bundle_25_'|| UPPER (MON)
  || '_Q'|| UPPER (QUARTER) ||'_' || UPPER (YEAR_P)|| '
   AS
   SELECT customer_id, otxact
     FROM ordertrailer INNER JOIN orderhdr_all ON ohxact = otxact
    WHERE sncode = 343 AND ohentdate = ''1-aug-2014'' AND ohstatus = ''IN''');
```

you'd then be trying to run:

```
CREATE TABLE SMS_Bundle_25_AUG_Q1_14
   AS
   SELECT customer_id, otxact
     FROM ordertrailer INNER JOIN orderhdr_all ON ohxact = otxact
    WHERE sncode = 343 AND ohentdate = '1-aug-2014' AND ohstatus = 'IN'
```

which at least looks more viable, assuming the tables you're selecting from exist. No idea why you're passing the year and quarter numbers as strings or applying `upper()` to them. And presumably you really want the `select` to be filtered on the same year and month as the table name.

It's useful to display the command you're trying to execute, for example with `dbms_output`, to see exactly what you've created; and you can then also run that manually to see where it's going wrong more clearly.

But as noted in comments, it's unusual to create objects from a procedure like this. Your schema should usually be static, not modified on the fly. You won't be able to refer to this table from other code unless that is also being built dynamically. You seem to be creating a table as a snapshot of the other tables; a view or a materialised view might be more appropriate. But I'm not really sure why you're doing this so it's not entirely clear what you should be doing instead.